# Convert 1D String to multidimensional array - Numpy

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have theses points that I need to be in a 2,N array. I tried using Numpy but couldn't get it to work. Any help will do.

```
30.90,401.01;96.91,384.22;80.70,340.79;67.38,337.90;55.80,300.26;72.01,299.68;92.28,310.10;99.81,331.53;92.86,340.79;108.49,380.16;108.49,382.48;168.13,373.22;352.83,380.74;474.43,393.48;535.80,409.69;560.70,369.16;550.28,362.79;562.44,333.26;592.55,328.05;605.28,329.79;594.28,363.95;572.28,370.32;549.12,413.17;714.14,469.33;716.45,479.17;203.45,479.75;0.00,479.17;0.22,365.11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `matrix`:

```
s = '30.90,401.01;96.91,384.22;80.70,340.79'
np.array(np.matrix(s))
```

Output:

```
array([[ 30.9 , 401.01],
       [ 96.91, 384.22],
       [ 80.7 , 340.79]])
```

Comment: This `np.matrix` option was intended as a convenience for programmers who are used to creating matrices in MATLAB.  But look at the `np.matrix` docs.